# Couldn't decrypt config/credentials.yml.enc. Perhaps you passed the wrong key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-6

I recently deleted my local project but did a git clone and picked up from where I last committed. As I tried to upload images to AWS, which was already configured, I got this error:

```
Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError in RentalsController#create


Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: missing credentials, provide credentials with one of the following options: - :access_key_id and :secret_access_key - :credentials - :credentials_provider
```

I tried to look at my `credentials.yml` file for any error but when I input this command:

```
EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

...I get this error:

```
Couldn't decrypt config/credentials.yml.enc. Perhaps you passed the wrong key?
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You are missing the `master.key`

When you create a new project, rails will setup the `credentials.yml.enc` and a matching `master.key` file to access the credentials. The `master.key` file will also automatically be added to the gitignore, so if you delete your project local and clone it again your `master.key` will be lost.

The only way to fix this is by setting up new `credentials.yml.enc` and add your AWS credentials to it again.

First you need to remove the existing `credentials.yml.enc` and then run:
`rails credentials:edit` to create a new one.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer, it helped me solve the same problem as the OP. However I have a further question, this now means that I have a changed `credentials.yml.enc` file that could be staged for commit. My gut feeling is that I should not commit this as it is created with a different master key to my production app. What would be a good solution for this changed file? Should it be gitignored?

Comment: You should commit this and set the new `master.key` for your production app. You cannot use the old file because you lost the `master.key`. If you didn't lose the `master.key` than you shouldn't create a new `credentials.yaml.enc` at all and just put back your `master.key`

Comment: For those of us who don't do a first deploy very often, this is easy to forget.  And since the source of this error is well understood, surely Rails itself could provide a more useful error message that suggests the exact root cause given the context.

Comment: In my case I store master key in env. variable. I can see all credentials when I go to rails console with `Rails.application.credentials`. But when I try to use `bin/rails credentials:edit` I get error that it couldn't decrypt config/credentials.ymc.enc - what am I missing?

Comment: @Jared You might need to remove the old `credentials.yml.enc` file before running `credentials:edit`