# Rails 7 can't edit credentials.yml.enc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Before today, there's no problems at all!

But today, when I what to edit credentials.yml.enc by using the following command:

```bash
EDITOR='code --wait' bin/rails credentials:edit
```

It will open `development.yml.enc` but not `credentials.yml.enc`, so I just can't edit `credentials.yml.enc` now...

What should I do?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348058/couldnt-decrypt-config-credentials-yml-enc-perhaps-you-passed-the-wrong-key

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

1. Remove `development.yml.enc` or other environment-specific credential files you have.
2. Run `EDITOR='code --wait' bin/rails credentials:edit`
3. Edit your `credentials.yml.enc`.

I believe here's your case:

> If you have a config/credentials/development.yml.enc file and are in
> the development environment, then that is what credentials:edit will
> edit.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/50080